# Wordpress mysql query not showing results?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

The query should return thumbnail, title, name, price etc (all the fields)

```
<?php 
query_posts('meta_key=cp_job&meta_value=Sell'); 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        the_content(); 
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

It should return results where `meta_key=cp_job` and `meta_value=Sell`.. I've tried all sorts of queries and this has taken up several hours, as i've yet to find a solution.

I'm working with a theme and the only time i've gotten a result is with this query

```
     $metakey = 'cp_job';
  $job = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );

    foreach ($job as $value) {
      echo $value";
    }
```

This query doesn't do what i want to accomplish.

I simply want `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE cp_job='Sell'";` but WordPress makes everything so complicated. I don't even know the table which hold my results!...

Any help please..

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post', // Or custom post type if it's a CPT
    'meta_key'   => 'cp_job',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'cp_job',
            'value'   => 'Sell'
        )
    )
);
```

Then run the query and loop the `$query` same way:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```